# I need to pick data 100K rows from csv(one column named code) and sent in response as json in batch of 5K in jmeter

Tags: json, csv, jmeter

I need to pick data 100K rows from csv (one column named code) and sent in response as json request in batch of 5K in each request jmeter. how to achieve this with jsr223 test element?

request json will be like:

```
{
 "Codes": [
{
  "CodeName": "{value from csv}"
}
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder
import groovy.json.internal.LazyMap

def data = new ArrayList()
def lines = new File('codes.csv').readLines()

0.upto(4999, {
    def entry = new LazyMap()
    entry.put('CodeName', lines.get(it as int))
    data.add(entry)

})

def builder = new JsonBuilder()

builder(Codes: data.collect {[CodeName: it.get('CodeName'),]})

log.info(builder.toPrettyString())
vars.put('batch', builder.toPrettyString())
```

Should produce the needed JSON and store it into `${batch}` JMeter Variable.

Demo:

[image: JMeter JSON Builder Groovy]

References:

- [Groovy: JsonBuilder](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonBuilder.html)
- [Groovy: Parsing and producing JSON](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Thanks for the response @Dimitri. It pretty much did the work for me but I have a scenario where I need to send next 5K values from csv in the next iteration or for the different thread. is there a way to achieve this? like the first iteration takes the first 5k and second takes next 5k values from csv.